# CFReadStreamHasBytesAvailable polling - best practices

Tags: iphone, cocoa, cocoa-touch, network-programming, core-foundation

I'm currently polling my `CFReadStream` for new data with `CFReadStreamHasBytesAvailable`.

(First, some background: I'm doing my own threading and I don't want/need to mess with runloop stuff, so the client callback stuff doesn't really apply here).

My question is: what are accepted practices for polling?

[Apple's documentation](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Networking/Conceptual/CFNetwork/CFStreamTasks/chapter_4_section_4.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000230-62008) on the subject doesn't seem too helpful.

They recommend to "do something else while you wait".  I'm currently just doing something along the lines of:

```
while(!done)
{
  if(CFReadStreamHasBytesAvailable(readStream))
  {
    CFReadStreamRead(...) ... bla bla bla
  } else {
    usleep(3600); // I made this up
    sched_yield(); // also made this up
    continue;
  }
}
```

Is the `usleep` and the `sched_yield` "good enough"?  In there a "good" number to sleep for in `usleep`?

(Also: yes, because this is running in my own thread, I could just block on `CFReadStreamRead` - which would be great but I'm also trying to snag upload progress as well as download progress, so blocking there wouldn't help...).

Any insight would be much appreciated - thanks!

Comment: you don't have a separate thread for upload and download?

Comment: Each request effectively has its own thread.

Comment: maybe there is some requirement I'm not understanding but if upload and download are assigned to their own threads then does the problem go away? i.e. then you just have one thread reading the stream, one writing it, each blocking. however you need to synchronise them.

Comment: There's no need for two threads, I can get all the info I need from the ReadStream (I don't need/have a write stream).  I'm polling the ReadStream from a background thread, the question is what is a "good" way to poll?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this question is a bit of a paradox because you're asking what the best practices are for doing something that's intrinsically not a best practice ;)

When there's a perfectly good method for blocking on network I/O, any compromise that causes you to poll instead is by definition not the best practice.

That said, if you do poll I think it might be more appropriate to "run the runloop until date" on your thread, instead of using whatever posix sleep or yield method you're imagining.  Remember that each thread gets its own runloop, so essentially by running the runloop you're allowing Apple to employ its concept of best practices for blocking until a future date.

As for the time delay, I don't know if you'll get a definitive answer for what a good time is. It's a tradeoff between peppering the CPU with polling cycles vs. being stuck in the runloop for a little while when I/O is ready to be read from the network.

Ideally I think I would refocus your efforts on making this work using I/O blocking calls, but if you stick with the poll & idle technique, don't fret too much about the specific delay time. Just pick something that works and doesn't seem to impact performance negatively in either direction.

(Also, I'd like to clarify that I'm not too religious about the polling vs. blocking thing, I'm only stressing its value because you're obviously in search of an elevated solution).

Comment: You're certainly not wrong :). I'm using plain, ol' threads, no runloops associated with them. I figured I'd avoid the overhead of a runloop (negligible?). I also figured polling was going to happen at some level in the system, so I might as well do it myself - though I might be wrong about that.

Comment: I think you are wrong about the presumption that polling will happen at some lovel in the system.

The way the runloop-based CFStream stuff works is at some point where the network I/O is actually being waited on, it literally becomes a hardware-driven wakeup. So there's no polling, just waiting.

Comment: Yep, you're right. I suppose the best way to do this then is to use a runloop and schedule a timer to periodically check upload status. (Or use CFRunLoopRunInMode to force the runloop to hand back control to me periodically - overhead difference?).

Comment: Either way, the whole reason I'm doing this is completely up in smoke (unless I can come up with a fix).  No way to accurately grab upload progress for small transfers: https://devforums.apple.com/thread/9352?tstart=0

Answer (score 1):

When doing manual CFStream based connections on a separate thread (for custom things like bandwidth monitoring and throttling), I use a combination of CFReadStreamScheduleWithRunLoop, CFRunLoopRunInMode and CFReadStreamSetClient. Basically I run for 0.25 seconds and then check stream status. The client callback also gets notified on its own as well. This allows me to periodically check read status and do some custom behavior but rely mostly on (stream) events.

```
static const CFOptionFlags kMyNetworkEvents =
kCFStreamEventOpenCompleted
| kCFStreamEventHasBytesAvailable
| kCFStreamEventEndEncountered
| kCFStreamEventErrorOccurred;

static void MyStreamCallBack(CFReadStreamRef readStream, CFStreamEventType type, void *clientCallBackInfo) {
    [(id)clientCallBackInfo _handleNetworkEvent:type];
}


- (void)connect {
  ...

  CFStreamClientContext streamContext = {0, self, NULL, NULL, NULL};
  BOOL success = CFReadStreamSetClient(readStream_, kMyNetworkEvents, MyStreamCallBack, &streamContext);


  CFReadStreamScheduleWithRunLoop(readStream_, CFRunLoopGetCurrent(), kCFRunLoopDefaultMode);

  if (!CFReadStreamOpen(readStream_)) {
    // Notify error
  }

  while(!cancelled_ && !finished_) {

    SInt32 result = CFRunLoopRunInMode(kCFRunLoopDefaultMode, 0.25, NO);

    if (result == kCFRunLoopRunStopped || result == kCFRunLoopRunFinished) {
      break;
    }

    if (([NSDate timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate] - lastRead_) > MyConnectionTimeout) {
      // Call timed out
      break;
    }

    // Also handle stream status CFStreamStatus status = CFReadStreamGetStatus(readStream_);
    if (![self _handleStreamStatus:status]) break;
  }

  CFRunLoopStop(CFRunLoopGetCurrent());


  CFReadStreamSetClient(readStream_, 0, NULL, NULL);
  CFReadStreamUnscheduleFromRunLoop(readStream_, CFRunLoopGetCurrent(), kCFRunLoopDefaultMode);

  CFReadStreamClose(readStream_);       

}


- (void)_handleNetworkEvent:(CFStreamEventType)type {
    switch(type) {
        case kCFStreamEventOpenCompleted:
            // Notify connected
            break;

        case kCFStreamEventHasBytesAvailable:
            [self _handleBytes];
            break;

        case kCFStreamEventErrorOccurred:
            [self _handleError];
            break;

        case kCFStreamEventEndEncountered:
            [self _handleBytes];
            [self _handleEnd];
            break;

        default:
          Debug(@"Received unexpected CFStream event (%d)", type);
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Isn't handling the status yourself kind of antithetical to the purpose of runloops? It's supposed to notify you if case of events, right?